# reserve() memory multi-dimensional std::vector (C++)

Tags: c++, memory-management, multidimensional-array, stdvector

Let's we have

```
std::vector <std::vector <unsigned short int>> face;
face.resize(nElm);
```

Its OK to `resize()` for the first dimension. However, I also want to `reserve()` memory for the elements of face; I mean for the second dimension. (I am aware of the difference between `resize()` and `reserve()`)

Comment: `resize()` and `reserve()` are not the same thing. Which of the two are you asking about? The wording of the question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Go accept some answers to your previous questions, please. There are plenty of good ones to choose from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do

```
face.resize(nElm);
for(auto &i : face) i.resize(nDim2);
```

or if you do not use c++11:

```
face.resize(nElm);
for(std::vector < std::vector < unsigned short int> >::iterator it
                =face.begin();it!=face.end();++it) {
   it->resize(dim2);
}
```

If you want to just `reserve` for the second dimension then just do that instead of `resize`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *resize* it, then you need to

```
for(auto i=face.begin(),ie=face.end();i!=ie;++i) i->resize(nElm);
```

(since there's no space between two closing angle brackets, I assumed you're using `c++11`).

If, on the other hand, you want to *reserve* memory, you'd have to do it when you actually have a vector, that is — an element on the first dimension.

Comment: With `face.resize(nElm);` I actually have a vector, do I? It seems I should reserve one by one for each first dimension as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the loop above does.

Comment: (just a bit more efficiently than the one in accepted answer:))

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to loop through the first dimension and resize the second, either using iterators or a simple;

```
for (int i=0; i<nElm; i++) {
    face[i].resize(nElm2ndDimension);
}
```